# Execution of sort operation in stream operation

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    List<Integer> l = list.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).limit(10).sorted((i, j) -> j.compareTo(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    l.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This will filter elements until we reach limit 10 and then sort those 10 elements. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Looks altight here https://repl.it/repls/FloralwhiteRectangularUpgrade

Answer (score 1):

Logically this means that `collect` will ask an item from the `limit`, `limit` from the  `filter`, and `filter` from the `stream`.

**Streams** are lazy because intermediate operations are not evaluated unless terminal operation is invoked.

*Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as `filter()` does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.*

The chain of operations is lazily evaluated in reverse order going from `collect()` to `filter()`, values are consumed by each step as soon as they are produced by the previous step.